# JPA/Hibernate sql statement with collection inside another collection, is possible?

Tags: hibernate

How can I write this jpa/hibernate sql statment (if its possible )

I have 2 entitys

```
@Entity
public class Employees    
  @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
  private List<Benefits> benefits;
```

=======================================

```
@Entity    
public class Benefits
  private String department
```

I need to retrieve a list of employees that have on your list of 
benefits which are included in a some list of departments.

I wrote the following JPA/Hibernate sql statement,

```
from Employees e where e.benefits exists ( from Benefits b where b.department in (?1) )", someListOfDepartments )
```

but it throws an exception. Is it possible to do such query?

Comment: Can you post the exception? do you use actual native SQL queries or HQL/Criteria?

Comment: Hi , it´s java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: exists near line ...    I think I use HQL/Criteria. Thank´s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HQL:

```
from Employees e INNER JOIN e.benefits b where b.department in (:depts)
```

Criteria:

```
session.createCriteria(Employees.class);
    criteria3.createAlias("benefits", "b",
            CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN)
            .setFetchMode("b", FetchMode.JOIN)
    .add(Restrictions.in("b.department", depts));
```